# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity and a short exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field and $\mathcal{F}$ coherent over $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{k}$, $H\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}_{k}$ a hyperplane.

In Nitsure's paper [Construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590), page 9 right at the bottom, the author talks about a short exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
    0\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}(m-i-1)\longrightarrow^{\alpha}\mathcal{F}(m-i)\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_{H}(m-i)\longrightarrow 0\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where

> (...) the map $\alpha$ is locally given by multiplication with a defining equation of $H$, (...)

What exactly is meant by that: *multiplication by a defining equation*. I mean $H$ is locally given by some equation, sure, but what exactly do I have to multiply by that equation in order to get the map $\alpha$? I am confused.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ as a graded module $M$ then you can think of the above short exact sequence as a short exact sequence of graded components of modules

\begin{equation*}
    0\longrightarrow M(m-i-1)\longrightarrow^{\alpha} M(m-i)\longrightarrow M(m-i)/\alpha M(m-i-1)\longrightarrow 0\text{,}
\end{equation*}

where the map $\alpha$ is just the multiplication map by $\alpha$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is the multiplication map by $\alpha$. What do you mean by that tautology?

Comment: In this setting, $\alpha$ is just an element in the homogenous coordinate ring $k[x_0,\ldots ,x_n]$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What element is $\alpha$?

Comment: A linear form defining $H$.

Comment: Aaah I see my mistake. I forgot that $H$ was a hyper*plane*, I somehow had had an arbitrary codim-1-subvariety in mind.